# How do I open an html file in java?

Tags: java, html, file, browser, default

I want to open an html file in java from a specific directory. I cannot use Desktop.open() because it is not the default browser, so how else can I do this? Thanks.

Comment: [Use the jsoup library](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/input/load-document-from-file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a script file say open.bat or open.sh.In your executable file,write the code for opening of HTML file using the preferred browser.

Then use `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("open.bat");`